# How to add seperator on select2 options?

Tags: jquery-select2

I am using select2 js plugin to show my dropdown list.
But after 5 options I want to show a seperator on the options, which will not be selectable and searchable?
[image]

Can anyone please help me to do so?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you can do it using optgroup